# Word frequencies in unbalanced case-control dataset

Tags: statistics, normalization, class-imbalance

I have a case-control cohort for which I'm doing analysis of clinical notes. The ratio of cases to controls is 1:4. What I'm looking at is the relative frequency of certain words (e.g. overdose, suicide) for each group and from documents spanning a 30-day period.
For days numbered 1 to 30, for cases and controls, I want to count the number of times each word is mentioned in all documents for that day. I wish to visualise the results in a plot of some description.

There are two factors of imbalance in the data set:

1. the number of individuals in each group, i.e. the case-control ratio
2. the number of documents for each group - cases have on average more documents per day than controls

The first is easily mitigated by dividing control counts by 4, but what is a reliable way to offset the difference in relative number of documents between cases and controls?